# Java equivalent for System.Action in .NET

Tags: java, c#

In .NET under `System.Action` the following methods are available.

1. `Invoke()`
2. `BeginInvoke(AsyncCallback, object)`
3. `EndInvoke(IAsyncresult)`

How do I get the *Java* equivalent for the above methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unlike C#, Java has no delegates. So I don't think there is an equivalent for `System.Action`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting form `Java 7` you can use `Executors` framework. You can find a couple of examples: [here](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/)

One of the examples shown there (copied "as is" from [the link above](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/) - an example is for `Java 8` because of `lambda`):

```
Callable<Integer> task = () -> {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        return 123;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("task interrupted", e);
    }
};

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(task);
```

**Invoke** equivalent:

```
int result = task.call();
```

**BeginInvoke** equivalent:

```
Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(task);
```

**EndInvoke** equivalent:

```
int result = future.get();
```